# Trying to recode a list variable based on the lengths method

Tags: r, list, recode

I have a variable that stores user enter race data. The survey allowed people to choose 1 or multiple races. The survey separated the entries using a semicolon. I used strsplit to convert the str variable into a list variable. I want to assess the number of members in each index and recode any response with more than on entry to "multiracial" and if only one race was enter than pass that value into the new variable. I have been able to get the following to recode the variable to either Multiracial or Single but I want to pass the original value if there is only one value in the index.

```
Combined %>% 
  select(Race_List) %>%
  mutate(Race_Number = if_else(lengths(Race_List) > 1,
                                 "Multiracial",
                                  "Single")) %>% 
  count(Race_Number) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  View()
```

So I tried this:

```
Combined %>% 
  select(Race_List) %>%
  mutate(Race_Number = if_else(lengths(Race_List) > 1,
                                 "Multiracial",
                                  Race_Number)) %>% 
  count(Race_Number) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  View()
```

This gives me the following error:

Error in View : Problem while computing `Race_Number = if_else(lengths(Race_List) > 1, "Multiracial", Race_Number)`.

I am very new to R and I am probably missing something obvious or more likely using the wrong methods. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Thank you, Shawn. I will try to do that.